# Is there a way to have a watch function get the name of the file being watched?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have coded these three watches but need to code more:

```
gulp.task('fl-index', function () {
    gulp.watch('index-fl.html', function () {
        return gulp.src('index-fl.html')
          .pipe(rename('index.html'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    })
});

gulp.task('ic-index', function () {
    gulp.watch('index-ic.html', function () {
        return gulp.src('index-ic.html')
          .pipe(rename('index.html'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    })
});

gulp.task('ts-index', function () {
    gulp.watch('index-ts.html', function () {
        return gulp.src('index-ts.html')
          .pipe(rename('index.html'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    })
});
```

As all the functions are pretty much the same I was wondering is it possible for me to some way combine this into one gulp task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you pass to `gulp.watch()` receives an object that contains a `path` property pointing to the affected file every time a change occurs.

You can use this to unify your three tasks:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('index', function () {
  gulp.watch('index-*.html', function (file) {
    return gulp.src(path.basename(file.path))
      .pipe(rename('index.html'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  })
});
```